# Spring-MVC: Get full-fledged object instead of string when using 'select-options'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the class `Lesson`, which holds the reference to `Course` object, like so:

```
public class Lesson {
    ...
    private Course course;
    ...
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
       this.course = course;
    }
    ...
}
```

And I want to set the `Course` property on the `Lesson` object through the select form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addLesson" modelAttribute="lesson">
 <form:select path="course">
  <form:options items="${courses}"/>
 </form:select>
 <input type="submit" name="addLesson" value="Add lesson">
</form:form>
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
@Controller
public class LessonController {
    @Autowired
    private LessonRepository lessonRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    // form setup
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSchedule(ModelMap model) {
        ...
        model.addAttribute("lesson", new Lesson());
        model.addAttribute("courses", courseRepository.findAll());
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addLesson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addLesson(@ModelAttribute("lesson") Lesson lesson, BindingResult result) {
        lessonRepository.save(lesson);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is that it passes the `String` representation of the `Course` object (defined by `toString()`) to the `course` setter of the `Lesson` object.

How do I properly set the `Course` property of the `Lesson` object using my select form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for UI rendering `Formatter<T>` is used with ConversionService. But prior to Spring 3, `PropertyEditors` were used.

I've shared sample github project for your case https://github.com/jama707/SpringSelectBoxSample

```
@Component("courseFormatter")
public class CourseFormatter implements Formatter<Course> {
    private CourseRepository courseRepository=new CourseRepository();


    @Override
    public String print(Course course, Locale arg1) {
        return course.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Course parse(String actorId, Locale arg1)  {
        return courseRepository.getCourse(actorId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html)  you need to set `itemValue` and `itemLabel`on the `form:options` tag, otherwise ,as you already mentioned, the value will be the `toString()` of the Object, `itemValue` and `itemLable` should refer to properties from your `Course` bean.

Assuming that your `Course` class has a property `name`, then your form should look like this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addLesson" modelAttribute="lesson">
 <form:select path="course">
  <form:options items="${courses}"  itemValue="name" itemLabel="name"/>
 </form:select>
 <input type="submit" name="addLesson" value="Add lesson">
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the course object directly instead of some course object property by using [Spring Converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#core-convert).

Implement the Converter interface which in your case may convert selected courseName to Course:

```
public class CourseConverter implements Converter<String, Course> {
    public Course convert(String source) {
    List<Course> courseList = //Populate courseList the way you did in Lesson
    Course course = //Get course object based on selected courseName from courseList;
    return course;
    }
}
```

Now register the converter:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" >
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="your.package.CourseConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and change your form:options as:

```
<form:options items="${courses}"  itemValue="courseName" itemLabel="courseName"/>
```